# Can I restrict access to an attachment to a Trello card?

Tags: trello, attachment

Is there a way that I can define access to an attachment on a card in a Trello list. I only want project sponsors to be able to access a specific document. If there is no way to do this, will Trello support a password protected Word document, such that only those with the password can open?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to define access to an attachment in Trello.  However, any type of file that is less than 10MB can be uploaded, so uploading a password-protected Word file will not be a problem.